# Remove most common words mallet

Tags: lda, mallet, pruning

I create from a list of strings a list of instances consisting of token feature sequences. Via command line, I can prune those data based on counts, tf-idf etc. (https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/classify/tui/Vectors2Vectors.java). But what if I want to do it in Java? How do I have to extend my code?

My target is to remove most common words for LDA topic modeling.

```
public static InstanceList createInstanceList(List<String> texts) {

    ArrayList<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>();

    pipes.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence());
    pipes.add(new TokenSequenceLowercase());
    pipes.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords());
    pipes.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());

    InstanceList instanceList = new InstanceList(new SerialPipes(pipes));

    instanceList.addThruPipe(new ArrayIterator(texts));
    return instanceList;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code that you linked to for examples, starting around line 125. The `FeatureCountTool` generates term frequency and document frequency information. You can then generate a pruned alphabet and construct a new instance list, as in `Vectors2Vectors`, or generate a new stoplist `Set` and reimport the documents from the source files.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be a class available to prune, but then this is the way to go.